# how to store temp data in any method php

Tags: php, session

i have facing a problem with my temp data .
i am getting values from while loop and want to store it temporary for other pages .
for example

```
 $select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book");
while($u=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

    $i=$u['book-id'];

    }
```

i want to store the book id in session and wanted to get in outside the loop i use this method but its not working

```
  $select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book");
while($u=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

    $i=$u['book-id']';
$_SESSION['bookids']=array();
$_SESSION['bookids'][]=$i;
}
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
while( $u=mysql_fetch_array( $select ) ) {
    $_SESSION['bookids'][]=$u['book-id'];
}
print_r( $_SESSION['bookids'] );
```

Comment: you have made mistake on book_id by single quote.Accept answer.

Answer (score 2):

You override $_SESSION['bookids'] with a new empty array in every loop.

Initialize the array outside the loop and don't forget to set `session_start()` at the beginn of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
$select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book");
$bookids=array();
while($u=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

    $i=$u['book-id'];
$bookids[]=$i;
}
$_SESSION['bookids']=$bookids;
```

Comment: You made the same mistake change `$i=$u['book-id']'` for `$i=$u['book-id']` (remove last quote) and there's no need to store data in `$i` variable `$bookids[]=$u['book-id'];`